# Using % and // to find divisors

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulus, greatest-common-divisor, floor-division

I'm working on a small assignment. The task is to program a money dispenser calculator. A basic version might produce the following output:

```
Initial amount ($): 348
$100
$100
$100
$20
$20
$5
$2
$1
```

Here's my attempt:

```
#Pseudocode:
"""
Ask user for amount
For each demonination in [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]:
    Integer-divide amount by demonination
    Subtract demonination from amount to leave residual
    If residual // demonination > 1, add 1 to the count of this note, and repeat
    Otherwise go to the next denomination
"""


def find_denom(amount):
    number_of_notes = 0
    banknotes = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2]
    for note in banknotes:
        residual = (amount // note)
        if residual // note > 1:
            number_of_notes += 1
    return residual, number_of_notes

amount = int(input("Enter initial amount ($): "))
residual, number_of_notes = find_denom(amount)
```

If I enter 348 as the initial amount, I get the following variable values: `amount=348`, `number_of_notes=3`, which is correct for the number of $100 notes in `amount`, and `residual=174`.

I'm just trying to get my `find_denom` function working first, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What is the function supposed to return?

Comment: Why do you divide `residual // note`? `residual` is the count of notes, all you care is whether it's more than 1. You don't need to divide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other to achieve what you want, use can use this function

```
def find_denom(amount):
    banknotes = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
    for note in banknotes:
        counter = 0 # reassign zero to counter for every loop
        if note <= amount:
            number_of_notes = amount // note  # get the number of each note in amount
            amount = amount % note  # assign the remaining amount to amount
            while counter < number_of_notes: # check it the number of counter has exceeded the number of notes 
                print('$'+str(note)) #convert note to str and concatenate $ with it and display the note
                counter += 1

amount = int(input("Enter initial amount ($): "))
find_denom(amount)
```

Comment: You don't need separate calculations of `//, %`, just use the little-known[`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) operator: `number_of_notes, amount = divmod(amount, note)`

Answer (score 0):

The variable you name `residual` isn't the residual, it's the count of that note. To get the residual, multiply the note by the count, and subtract that from the amount. You can also get this same number using the `%` modulus operator.

You should find the first bank note that's less than amount, then perform the calculation.

```
def find_denom(amount):
    banknotes = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2]
    for note in banknotes:
        if note <= amount:
            number_of_notes = amount // note
            residual = amount % note
            return residual, number_of_notes
    return amount, 0
```

Comment: You don't need separate calculations of `//, %`, just use the little-known[`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) operator: `number_of_notes, amount = divmod(amount, note)`